# field names are not accessible in private static method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

inside my winform I have dozen of txt fields like
txtName, txtTitle, etc. Those fields are accessible inside constructor or on btnOk action but I want to on certain command to call private static method which will populate all txt fields with loaded object data. So I have

```
public AddEditForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and I tried with

```
 private static PopulateFormFields(Book book)
 {
      if(book !=null)
      {
           // txtName.Text = book.Name;
           // txtName var is not accessible here
      }        
      else
      {
           throw new Exception("You must provide valid book instance!");
      }
 }
```

Comment: use `public void` instead.

Comment: Obviously not, static methods do not have access to instance fields. That is precisely their purpose. Remove the `static` and you'll be fine; Or explain to us why this method _needs_ to be static. And declare a return type, even if it's `void`.

Comment: thanks... removed static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static method cannot directly access fields or controls declared as instance variables in the same class.
The static method needs an actual instance of the class to work on because these variables exists only when you declare and initialize an instance of the form.

What you need to do is pass the instance inside the static method

```
    private static void PopulateFormFields(AddEditForm current, Book book)
    {
        if(book !=null)
        {
           current.txtName.Text = book.Name;

        }        
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("You must provide valid book instance!");
        }
    }
```

And inside the current instance of AddEditForm call the static private method with

```
    AddEditForm.PopulateFormFields(this, book);
```

EDIT: I have forgot to say that you could also remove the static keyword from the method. In this case the method is accessible without using the class name identifier and can access the variables (fields, controls) of the current instance. (Merits go to `Kris Vandermotten` and its comment above also to notice the missing void keyword)

Answer (score -1):

The "txt fields" are instance variables of your form so will never be accessible by a static method.

Comment: they are accessible but only thing you cannot access them directly